# What is the best way to index email address in MYSql

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a signup table with millions of email id record in it. Email ids are unique. What is the best way to index them and fetch them back using asp.net for authentication purpose? I mean should I define email id column as a clustered unique index rather than UNIQUE?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MSSQL? MySQL doesn't have clustered unique index. You could hash the email (say, with `sha1`) and save it as binary, which reduces footprint to 20 bytes every time, and next to that column have the plaintext value of email address. Make the hash unique, now you have fixed-length unique identifier.

Comment: What is the point of hashing the email addresses, convert them into binary and then storing them in the database next to email column. It will increase the size of the database. It will not solve my problem rather would increase it. I want to reduce the query time by implementing indexing.

Comment: email addresses have variable length. If you hash a variable length value, your indexes will vary, and there are other issues with indexes when you try to index a value that's too large. To reduce that problem, you don't index the actual string-value of the email but its hash because hashes are fixed-length. It does solve your problem and you don't have anything to convert back or forth.

Comment: @Mjh How can I hash the emails.Can you please elaborate with an example?

Comment: Sure, any chance you can show table definition?

Comment: I have signup table which contains user_Id(Primary key AutoIncrement). first_name(not null), surname(could be null), mobile_number(could be null and Unique), email address(Not Null and Unique) and password field.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; what you provided is missing charset and a few other things.

Comment: @Mjh - a MySQL (with InnoDB) `PRIMARY KEY` _is_ `UNIQUE` _and_ clustered.

Comment: @RickJames - I'd really love to believe you, but I don't know who you are so if you could, please, show me in InnoDB's source code that what you're saying is true - I'd appreciate it and I'd even learn something new.

Comment: @Mjh - Will you accept the [_reference manual_](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-index-types.html) ?  I have not (and do not want to) read the source code.  My credentials..  17 years of _using_ MySQL; 34K 'reputation' on _this_ forum; mostly on tag [mysql]; provided about 26K answers across multiple forums, rarely with "you are wrong" feedback.  Toot, toot.

Comment: @RickJames - the page also says if there is no *suitable* unique index, it creates a hidden one. What is suitable index and how exactly is the index used in clustering - it's not explained in details. Please don't get me wrong, but imaginary numbers next to a person's name don't really mean much except you invested a lot of time in answering questions, which is commendable of course but doesn't always mean you'd be correct. Thanks for the reference from the manual though, I'll try to dig out the source to see whether it just uses the first unique index regardless of "suitability".

Comment: @Mjh - InnoDB picks the PK in this priority (it's in the manual somewhere):  (1) explicit `PRIMARY KEY`; (2) the 'first' `UNIQUE` key with no nullable columns; (3) the hidden, fabricated, 6-byte integer that is monotonic but not consecutive (look up Jeremy Cole's blogs on such).

Comment: @Mjh - Which is more likely to give you the 'correct' answer?  A stranger who could be wrong?  Or reading through 10K lines of code that could have un-maintained comments, and cryptic C code that could be misinterpreted?  It is hard to say which is "safer", but I am sure the former is faster.

Comment: @RickJames - you're correct, and one of really helpful members - proven by your reputation here. Who's to give the correct answer? Code. Yes, it's slower, but it's a definite proof. Bottom line - I skipped the part with `unique` index being used for clustering. Yes, it will be used *if* a condition is satisfied. Neither you or I can, with 100% certainty, claim what would happen. We would have to read the code to see the logic behind clustering and what's chosen and how it's used. I believe you're correct, what you wrote makes sense, I won't argue that.

Comment: @RickJames also, given the context of this question and what OP is doing - yes, he can simply skip auto_increment and use email as primary key. Whether that's useful, faster, whether it does what he's after - he'll have to test. One thing is for sure - it really helps to have a nice number giving you record identification. That's my personal opinion. Your solution probably works, there's no indication it doesn't. I'll have a look at Jeremy Cole's blog, thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @Mjh - Jeremy _does_ look at code.  But then one has to trust his interpretation.  (I learned of the details of the hidden PK from him.)  Having a visible PK can help with maintenance.  (I learned that from experience.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you have a variable length textual input, such as e-mail or addresses, but you want them to be unique then the standard approach is to index the **hash** of that value.

Reason: hashes are fixed-length, and you are avoiding problems with text-data exceeding index length.

According to your comment, the table you have would look like this (I purposely omitted password and mobile number):

```
create table users (
    user_id int not null unsigned auto_increment,
    first_name varchar(255) not null,
    surname varchar(255) default null,
    email varchar(255) not null,
    primary key(id)
) engine = innodb;
```

I would alter that table and add a field that contains email hash. I'd maintain this has via a trigger, so that you can focus on getting valid data in without worrying about creating hashes. To do so, the field would be `binary(20)` since it will contain a raw hash and that takes 20 bytes. Since we want to maintain it via trigger, then we need to make that field nullable and unique. Note: you can make it `binary(40)`

Table:

```
create table users (
    user_id int not null unsigned auto_increment,
    email_hash binary(20) default null, -- this is the field in question
    first_name varchar(255) not null,
    surname varchar(255) default null,
    email varchar(255) not null,
    primary key(id),
    unique(email_hash) -- this is the unique index over the hash
) engine = innodb;
```

What we need now is a trigger that deals with email hashes. I'll show how to create the trigger which maintains this info before inserting. Similar logic applies for updating the table:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER users_before_insert BEFORE INSERT ON `users` 

FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.email_hash = UNHEX(SHA1(new.email)); -- You can remove UNHEX if you want human-readable value. You'll need binary(40) to hold it then
END;

DELIMITER ;
```

From within your application, you'd simply provide values for first name, surname and email. MySQL will take care of duplicates and it will signal you with the state of `23000`. I don't know how to use `asp.net` so you'll have to adjust to its error handling somehow.

You can handle hashes from within your asp.net application, but if you feel more comfortable by having the database do this - I showed how to achieve it via triggers.

The same rule would apply for mobile number, if you require it to be unique or any other fields. Naturally, hashing the number might produce longer values for the hash than the actual number is, in which case you might simply directly make the mobile number `unique`.

I hope this helps a bit in your decision on what to do.

Comment: I suppose the '$$' delimiter needed to be after "END".

Answer (score 0):

Too many things for a comment...

If you already have `INDEX(email)`, then simply turn it into `UNIQUE(email)`.  The table (data+index) size will not change (more than a little due to the `ALTER`).

If `email` is too big to index -- such as because it is `TEXT` -- then there is no way to add a `UNIQUE` index on `email`.  In this case, the "hash" solution would work.  Yes it would add megabytes to the disk usage, but this is unlikely to be an issue.

If you currently have `id AUTO_INCREMENT` and `PRIMARY KEY(id)`, then do you actually use `id` in other tables?  If not, then there are other paths we can discuss, such as making `email` or `hash` the `PRIMARY KEY`.  This *might* even shrink the disk footprint.

Regardless of what you do, use InnoDB.

Comment: How about this if don't store the hash of email id's rather just declare emai_id as a primary key and not null, will it do it for me? But primary key itself is a unique clustered index which could be a problem for me.

Comment: With `PRIMARY KEY(email)`, `INSERTing` the same email again will fail (duplicate key).  See also `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...`.

Answer (score -1):

If you're doing a unique key lookup it really doesn't make enough performance difference to worry about if the index is clustered or not.  It might make sense (or not) to cluster it as you add more things to the table.  The main thing is that you  have a unique constraint and most likely this will be the primary key so you'll get that and a corresponding index.  Performance will be fine - concern yourself with the other uses.  e.g. if you want to do an analysis on domain you might need to decompose the email address.  That might be more important.  Like most things, it depends....

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I want to clear one more thing. I have a separate ID column which I have declared as Primary Key but rather I am thinking to declare emailID as a primary key and Auto inc. as I have already declared it Unique. It will certainly reduce the size of my database if I have millions of record in it. Please do correct me If I am wrong. Thanks.. :)

Comment: @Deep - what is `emailID`? The value of email address? How do you plan to make that auto incremented? Just leave primary key as is, add the hash of the email as `unique` so you don't get duplicates and all your problems are gone. You can query fast, you can retrieve fast, you can insert only unique emails - don't overthink it because you'll find problems where there are none. Millions of records is nothing, so don't worry too much about millions of records.

Comment: You don't need an ID for this.  Even if you do decide to include it, you need to put a unique, not null constraint on email which is effectively the PK.  If you need a foreign key on email then maybe keep the ID but that's outside the scope of what you've described here.  Not sure why Mjh is so insistent about hashing the email - not necessary, complicates everything and leaves the door open for errors. I'd not do that.

Comment: @LoztInSpace - I'm not insistent, the standard way to approach the problem with unique variable input is to calculate a number representing that input - a hash. Using MySQL + InnoDB, and having a natural instead of surrogate primary key produces something unwanted - a hidden clustering key will be created, and it will be 8 bytes in length. So, by "hunting" for optimization, you'll actually inflate the index storage instead of deflate it. I'll leave the topic, there's no need to insist or enforce a solution on someone who wants to hear something else. Good luck guys and have a nice day!

Answer (score -1):

Hashing an Email Address Column in the Database for indexing can be achieved by altering DB to add a new field (email_hash)  :

```
ALTER TABLE user_meta ADD email_hash VARBINARY(32) NULL
```

Then set the value of the email_hash by:

```
UPDATE user_meta SET email_hash = MD5(email);
```

And then create a trigger like described , for example:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER users_meta_before_insert BEFORE INSERT ON 'user_meta'
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SET NEW.email_hash = MD5(email); -- You can remove UNHEX if you want human-readable value. You'll need binary(40) to hold it then
END;
DELIMITER ;
```

Also you may find this useful: https://www.koder.ly/2020/07/hashing-an-email-address/